# Facebook graph api feed response issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use this query in graph API

```
{id}/feed?fields=id,from,picture,link,story,comments.fields(like_count),created_time&limit=500
```

with two different access token

```
Generated by graph API => CAAC<br>
Generated by My Application => CAAI
```

graph api token return 86 feeds.
application token return 94 feeds.

Extra 8 feeds application token result are repeated post, they have same links, story, likes, comment_count, picture. But Different id and created time.

Unable to understand this thing. Permission to both tokens are same.